# Building an R package error with devtools::document

Tags: r, devtools, r-package, rprofile

I am building R packages using devtools. I've built a package with some functions that I'd like to include. And I'd like to load the package and its documentation at startup. My package files are located at the location:

```
'~/global/Rcode/Startup Package'
```

My .Rprofile file looks like this:

```
.First <- function(){
    library(devtools)
    location <- '~/global/Rcode/Startup Package'
    document(location)
}
```

However when I open R, the functions from the package are loaded but the documentation is not.

If I run the same lines of code after startup myself, namely:

```
library(devtools)
location <- '~/global/Rcode/Startup Package'
document(location)
```

then everything works and the package correctly documents. This thus seems like a rather weird bug!

(As a partial fix I can run

```
install(location)
```

and treat it like a normal r package and everything works fine, however this takes time and as I intend to update the package a lot and do not really want to have to run this every time, especially as the devtools option should work.)

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of `document` function. It's designed to convert roxygen comments in raw R code to .Rd documentation.

Comment: Yeah I realize that, however if you have a function in your package: f. And you implement devtools::document on your package then if you do ?f, then you should get the documentation for f. My point is that this doesn't work if you do it via a startup file which seems bizarre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure `utils` is loaded before loading `devtools` otherwise there's no `help` function for `devtools` to overwrite.

With .Rprofile:

```
.First = function(){
library(utils)
library(devtools)
document("./foo")
}
```

then R startup goes:

```
[stuff]
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Updating foo documentation
Loading foo
```

And `help` is `devtools` version:

```
> environment(help)
<environment: namespace:devtools>
```

Remove that `library(utils)` and you'll see the help function is the one in utils that won't find your package documentation.